# Simplifying to different units

Tags: units

Is there a way to force Mathematica to `UnitSimplify` to a different unit? For example, I would like  `kg m^2/s^2` to simplify to `N m` but it always simplifies to `J`. Is there a way to specify a units preference?

Comment: Related: [Implementing CGS unit system in Mathematica 9](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15358/implementing-cgs-unit-system-in-mathematica-9).  Of course `N m`/`J` are the trickiest as one would often want to use *both* in the same calculation.

Comment: See notebook [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7513/) for some ideas on how to do various conversions. For your example, the GroebnerBasis approach using Meters and Newtons as "lowest" variables can be adapted to do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use UnitConvert:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, 
     ("Kilograms"*"Meters"^2)/
       "Seconds"^2], 
   Quantity["Newton Meters"]]
```