# Is it possible to use Gaussian cgs units in Mathematica computations?

Tags: physics, units

I was trying to do computations in Gaussian cgs units, and of course I failed due to dimensional issues. For instance, $q_1 q_2/r$ cannot be converted to $\mathrm{erg}$ since Gaussian system uses $4\pi \epsilon_0 = 1$.

So, the question is: **Is it possible to use Gaussian cgs unit system in *Mathematica* computations?** "Using Gaussian cgs unit system" means, for instance, $V_\mathrm{coulomb}=q_1 q_2/r$; no doubt that the units themselves can be called in whatever suitable situation.

Personally I think the answer is no, because the only unit systems listed in documentation of `UnitConvert` are `"SIBase"`,`"SI"`,`"Imperial"`, and `"Metric"`. But I am asking to get confirmation, and hopefully we can settle an answer to benefit future Google searches of this topic.

Comment: Real physicists don't use units. ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Unfortunately I'm not a real physicist yet, so I can't comment on how real physicists work. What I do know is that I'm an undergrad math and physics student, who sometimes need units for numerical results. Even if I keep track of and leave out the units of my own data, the physical constants in Mathematica come with units (I guess real physicists remember the values of constants, but unfortunately I can't just yet). Another reason I found units useful is in detecting typos, as typos typically mess up the dimensions.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries By the way, I'm not against your comment, since I actually think it's true.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15358/implementing-cgs-unit-system-in-mathematica-9?rq=1 ? I have no experience with Mathematica's unit system and from a didactic point of view I would recommend working out the units and conversion factors yourself. If you want to get an intuition/understanding of unit systems  that is the only way to get it; trusting Mathematica's unit "black box" is not. @SjoerdC.deVries short comment goes in that direction; once you understand how units work you can work in whatever system you want.

Comment: @M.J.Steil Actually there were two reasons for that remark. Firstly, if you work in a nice unit system like SI then using units in your calculations are simply not necessary; you always know what you will end up with. Secondly, some theorists set c = 1 (dimensionless) to simplify their equations.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries If you get your constants/equations right you can calculate in CGS in Mathematica just like you would calculate in SI; without using `Quantity[]` for your variables. For that however you must get your constants right and check your equations for consistency yourself. This would be the way I would recommend; without using Mathematica's unit system, but that was not the question here.

Comment: @M.J.Steil Fortunately, I've since become a high energy theorist and I don't need units anymore ;) Everything is 1 for me.